# Likewise download for ubuntu 14.01 without internet connection

Tags: likewise

I have installed Ubuntu 14.01. I want to install likewise open. Can any one help me from where i have to download the likewise package. I don't have internet connection with my ubuntu machine. Also can any one tell me step by step procedure to install the package and precautions to take care. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Is it important to syncronise time and date in my windows server and Ubuntu machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: possible duplicate of [likewise-open | 14.04 | other easy way to connect AD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452904/likewise-open-14-04-other-easy-way-to-connect-ad)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the Ubuntu software on the [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/likewise-open) BUT Likewise is no more as of Ubuntu 12.04. The [ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen) has this to say:

> LikewiseOpen is now [Beyond Trust - PowerBroker Identity Services Open Edition](http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True) The Likewise website is gone, and links to it are broken. I have repaired some of them, but I have not found them all. The repositories are still using the likewise-open name, so the instructions are still good. However, the repo version in 12.04 will not work with the repo version of samba. Get the new branded version at http://www.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True

There is a download on that page for 32 and 64 bit versions of Ubuntu:

- [Linux 2.4/2.6 kernel 32-bit DEB](http://download.beyondtrust.com/PBISO/8.0.1/linux.deb.i386/pbis-open-8.0.1.2029.linux.x86.deb.sh)
- [Linux 2.4/2.6 kernel 64-bit DEB](http://download.beyondtrust.com/PBISO/8.0.1/linux.deb.x64/pbis-open-8.0.1.2029.linux.x86_64.deb.sh)

The download is an shell script; not a debian installer. So assuming you put it into "downloads" from command line:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod 664 pbis-open-8.0.1.2029.linux.x86.deb.sh
./pbis-open-8.0.1.2029.linux.x86.deb.sh
```

or for the 64 bit version:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod 664 pbis-open-8.0.1.2029.linux.x86_64.deb.sh
.pbis-open-8.0.1.2029.linux.x86_64.deb.sh
```

and the rest should be taken care of by the installer