# Joining and authenticated by Windiws Active Directory in Ubuntu 14.04 client

Tags: ldap, active-directory

Is there a easy GUI based tool to join Windows Active Directory?

I have read about "LikeWise" but does it work with Ubuntu 14.04?
It is not showing in my software centre.

Also in their website 14.04 is not listed!
Ref: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/likewise-open-gui/

Do we have similar alternative to "LikeWise"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, if nothing similar like "Likewise" or GUI based, then help me with something else, may be a command based.

Comment: just follow this steps http://askubuntu.com/questions/452904/likewise-open-14-04-other-easy-way-to-connect-ad

 and feed back me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now called PBIS Open 8.0.1

the same "LikeWise" . u can download it form here  and the same installation and GUI.

http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True&elq=1b2b5c66eaa3407fa00dfd5b7673ebcc&elqCampaignId=

Comment: ok i actually using it

Comment: bro, it did not work. provide detailed steps. thanks

Comment: just folww this steps http://askubuntu.com/questions/452904/likewise-open-14-04-other-easy-way-to-connect-ad