# Like wise open packages for Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, likewise

Please help me ASAP on installing Likewise open gui packages for ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS desktop version.

---

Thanks and Regards,
Raghava

Answer (score 2):

Likewise is unmaintained and have been removed from ubuntu repository.

Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen) :

> LikewiseOpen is now [Beyond Trust - PowerBroker Identity Services Open
>   Edition](http://likewiseopen.org/). The Likewise website is gone, and links to it are broken.

here is a [related discussion](https://askubuntu.com/q/452904/458410) about how to replace likewise

Comment: Then, could you please help me on how to join a ubuntu 14.04.3 desktop machine to Windows Active directory.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't , may be you should wait for an answer here or open another question, asking more specifically how to do that rather than how to install Likewise. Good luck