# E: Unable to locate package likewise?

Tags: package-management

I have problem when try to install any package error Unable to locate package ?
I tried to change the package software link and try a different connection some package problem solved except the problem package for likewise to help me to go in with MS domain network still I have this problem, could you help me to solve it ? 
Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [likewise-open | 14.04 | other easy way to connect AD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452904/likewise-open-14-04-other-easy-way-to-connect-ad)

Comment: To install PowerBroker Identity Services, download the .deb file and double-click to open it in the Software application.

Answer (score 1):

The [Likewise-Open](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen) package is only available for Ubuntu 12.04, as shown in this [package repository search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=likewise&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). The Ubuntu community wiki, which can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LikewiseOpen), states that the Likewise project appears to be discontinued, but seems to have been moved to an application called PowerBroker. The open edition is available from the [PowerBroker website](https://www.powerbrokeropen.org/), installation instructions are included in the Resources section of their website.

Comment: Thanks for your replay , but do you know any ubuntu built in package allow me to join Microsoft active directory .

Comment: @AhmedHussein If your problem is to join Microsoft Active directory from Ubuntu ask about that problem directly. You'll get better response that way